# can i use ingress-nginx to simple route traffic?

Tags: kubernetes, router, kubernetes-ingress

I really like the kubernetes Ingress schematics. I currently run `ingress-nginx` controllers to route traffic into my kubernetes pods.

I would like to use this to also route traffic to 'normal' machines: ie vm's or physical nodes that are not part of my kubernetes infrastructure. Is this possible? How?

Answer (score 3):

In Kubernetes you can define an externalName service in which you define a FQND to an external server.

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: my-service
  namespace: prod
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: my.database.example.com
```

Then you can use `my-service` in your nginx rule.

Comment: I used it all the time. If you combine it with kube-lego or cert-manager you can get ssl certs for free for services on your VMs.

Answer (score 1):

You can create static service and corresponding endpoints for external services which are not k8s and then use k8s service in ingress to route traffic.
Also you see ingress doc to enable custom upstream check 
https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#custom-nginx-upstream-checks

In below example just change port/IP according to your need

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    product: external-service
  name: external-service
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    protocol: TCP
 ---
 apiVersion: v1
 kind: Endpoints
 metadata:
   labels:
     product: external-service
   name: external-service
 subsets:
 - addresses:
   - ip: x.x.x.x
   - ip: x.x.x.x
   - ip: x.x.x.x
   ports:
   - name: http
     port: 80
     protocol: TCP
```

Answer (score -2):

I don't think it's possible, since ingress-nginx get pods info through watch namespace, service, endpoints, ingress resources, then redirect traffic to pods, without these resources specific to kubernetes, ingress-nginx has no way to find the ips that need loadbalance. And ingress-nginx doesn't has health-check method defined, it's up to the kubernetes builtin mechanic to check the health of the running pods.

Comment: using static service/endpoint, you can route traffic to external node as well and also with ingress you can enable health check for corresponding upstream as well.  https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#custom-nginx-upstream-checks

Comment: Ok, I learned a lot. Also I have a question, what's the probe method? tcp, http, can I define a  health-check url ?

Comment: You can not define tcp/http or URI check, it is default passive check for nginx, which is base on 2 params max_fails and fail_timeout.